# Можно ли в dataframe объединить ячейки?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

Как с помощью python создать датафрейм вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если имеется список названий столбцов:

```
a = ['Средний', 'Карие глаза', 'рост', 'вес']
```

И список значений:

```
b = [['Мужчины', 1.9, 0.003, '40%'], ['Женщины', 1.7, 0.002, '43%']]
```

Моя попытка:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=a)
with pd.ExcelWriter('ex.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
```

Но не получаю нужного результата

Answer (score 0):

`Pandas` не умеет не в прямоугольные таблицы. Максимум что тут можно попробовать - сделать мультииндекс для столбцов:

```
a = ['Пол', ('Средний', 'рост'), ('Средний', 'вес'), 'Карие глаза']
```

У меня нет возможности проверить, как это выведется в Эксель, но это по идее самое близкое к тому, что вы хотите.